# error when using kNN function from VIM package

Tags: r, knn

I'm trying to implement the KNN function in terms of data imputation for a variable in my dataset, below is the code i'm using;

```
Input_Data2 <- kNN(Input_Data, variable = c(Input_Data$Wind_Speed_knots))
```

However it keeps returning the below error;

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(imp_vars[index_imp_vars], FALSE)) : 
  Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates 
detected).
In addition: Warning message:
In m[is.na(m)] <- ncol(x) + seq_len(length(newnames)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Relatively new to this so not sure what's going wrong

Comment: Hard to say, since it depends on your `Input_Data`. Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: P.S. I removed the `vim` tag because it stands for `VI Improved`, the editor, not the R VIM package.